# Opencl in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, opencl

I installed ImageMagick using the instructions as below

> export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/include
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
>
> ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --enable-openmp --enable-opencl --without-dps --without-djvu --without-fftw --without-fpx --without-gslib --without-gvc
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

While checking the imageMagick installation using

> identify --version

It is showing as,

> Version: ImageMagick 7.0.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2016-04-06
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2016
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC License:
>   http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php Features: Cipher DPC
>   HDRI OpenCL OpenMP  Delegates (built-in): bzlib fontconfig freetype
>   jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib

When I check the device benchmark file as this :

```
$ cat ~/.cache/ImageMagick/ImagemagickOpenCLDeviceProfile
```

it shows

```
<version>ImageMagick Device Selection v0.9</version>
<device><type></type><name>Quadro M6000</name><driver>352.79</driver><max cu>24</max cu><max clock>1114</max clock><score>0.0960</score></device>
<device><type></type><score>1.1890</score></device>
```

But when i run the command

> time convert /home/downloads/lan.jpg -convolve '-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1' /home/downloads/convolve.png

I got the output as

> real  0m1.077s user   0m3.072s sys    0m0.032s

In OpenMP i got the output as

> real  0m0.946s user   0m3.096s sys    0m0.036s

When i worked with the convert binary file inside the package,

> ./convert /home/zlabs/lan.jpg -convolve '-1, -1, -1, -1, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1' /home/zlabs/convolve.png

i got

> real  0m0.904s user   0m1.824s sys    0m0.024s

Actually the binary file is giving actual performance of opencl. How is it possible? What is happening actually? Is Opencl working or not?

Comment: Put very heavy stress on this test(using very big images and many of them), check gpu temperature using msi-afterburner or speedfan. Then you can know if gpu is used efficiently.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik can u help with the commands to check it out in ubuntu

Comment: Those monitoring programs may not be supporting ubuntu I'm sorry.